# jQuery Dropdown Height Attr

Tags: jquery, css

I'm confused about why my dropdown only works perfectly fine half the time; http://spicyyeti.com/story_archive.html I believe if you open the preview, chances are the dropdown won't open to its full height. Although, sometimes the dropdown works fine, and when I test it offline, it works fine as well. What's the problem here?

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.item + .dropdown').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('data-height', $(this).height()).height(0);
        });

        $('.item').click( function() {
            $dropdown = $(this).find('+ .dropdown');
            if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $dropdown.animate({ height:'0' }, 400, "swing", function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('open');
                $dropdown.show().animate({ height: $dropdown.attr('data-height') }, 400, "swing");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the CSS for the dropdown...

```
<style> 
            .dropdown {
        display: block;
        width: calc(80% - 100px);
        background-color: white;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        margin: -10px auto;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        .dropdown h2 {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 29px;
        vertical-align: 60px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        }
        .dropdown h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: "Lobster Two", cursive;
        }
        .dropdown img {
        max-height: 150px;
        max-width: 150px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Quick question - are you setting a set height to your images, or their parent div?  I haven't delved into the code, but this problem may be caused by the plugin trying to get the height before the images fully load.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

according to @Alexander Lozada's  answer, try this

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
         $('.item + .dropdown').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('data-height', $(this).height()).height(0);
            });

         $('.item').click( function() {
            $dropdown = $(this).find('+ .dropdown');
            if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $dropdown.animate({ height:'0' }, 400, "swing", function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('open');
                $dropdown.show().animate({ height: $dropdown.attr('data-height') }, 400, "swing");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Difference between document.ready and window.load is

- document.ready fires up when DOM is loaded, not necessarily img is ready.
- window.load fires up when all frames, objects and images are fully loaded.

In your case, your js should wait for image loaded for its height.
Try progressive img to make your page loads faster.

Comment: Just tried with a local copy of the site - doesn't look like image height is the problem.  I'm thinking perhaps something in the jQuery is off.

EDIT: seems to be a problem with 'data-height'.  It is not accessing it.  When a static value is used it works correctly.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada he is setting the data-height when dom is ready. But the data-height is not correct when dom ready.  It should be set after the elements inside the .dropdown. So i think by using window.load it will fix the problem.

Comment: I tested this code on my local copy under 3G internet connection and it works fine. So it should work just fine on your end too.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to take another look.

Comment: (window).load actually does fix the problem. It seems the code wasn't off, but that jQuery was not reading the image heights. Apparently (window).load compared to (document).ready allows the images to load initially...

Comment: As this works in Chrome, Safari, and IE, it won't work in Firefox.

Comment: @carrmx just had another look at your website. when you set the src of img, use `/` not `\\`. can you please that so i can check again?

Comment: oh wow, i can't believe that was the problem. that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @carrmx lol, be careful when you use slashes. They made this very confusing. forward slash is for webs, and backward slash is for windows. When writing a website you rarely need to use backward slash. Chrome and other browser seem to handling it but firefox somehow failed. Im impressed IE didnt fail on this tho

Answer (score 4):

Well firstly, the way this is set up is a tad unconventional.  I'm not exactly sure what caused the code to do this, but I fixed it (slightly) below:

## **Original Way**

(Disclaimer - this isn't the best way of doing things - but I included just for the sake of letting you know what happened with your code.  For a better and much simpler way, skip to "An Easier Way" below!)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown').css('display','none')
            
        $('.item').click( function() {
            $dropdown = $(this).find('+ .dropdown');
            if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $dropdown.animate({ height:'0' }, 400, "swing", function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('open');
                $dropdown.show().animate({ height: $dropdown.data('height') }, 400, "swing");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let's take a look at what I've changed -

The first line is changed, so instead of changing the height of `.dropdown`, it is simply hidden.  `$dropdown.show()` reveals it later.

I've also replaced the `.attr('data-*')` with more legible `.data` jquery functions.  They do the same thing, but now you just write `height` as opposed to `data-height`.

It's important to remember that what you are showing will not be the same height as `.dropdown`.  Therefore, some example HTML might look like this -

```
<div class="dropdown" data-height="240" style="height: 98px;">
            <h1><a href="http://spicyyeti.com/maniacs1.html">FIRST</a>•<a href="http://spicyyeti.com/m/maniacs15.html">LAST</a></h1>
        </div>
```

While this works, this is a pretty simple example, and it's a lot easier to deal with without data attributes!

**BONUS EDIT:  I overlooked this, oops!...**

Well - simply removing the `height: 98px` attribute on your div seems to fix the problem partially as well. But don't be dissuaded - there is a better answer below, that you'll find much more maintainable. I'm not sure why your code is reading the actual height instead of the `data-height` as you specified.  It is possible that they are read as the same thing.

---

## An easier way

[I have a JSFiddle here that I will be explaining.](http://jsfiddle.net/nnr4805r/1/)

**HTML**
The HTML here is fairly standard and similar to your setup.  There are two of the same classes at work - `.item` - which triggers the open of `.dropdown`.  This is a simple example, but can be easily applied to the page you have already.

```
<div class="item">
    Click me!
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    content!<br>
    content!<br>
    content!<br>
    content!<br>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Click me!
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    content!<br>
    content!<br>

</div>
<div class="item">
    Click me!
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    content!<br>
    content!<br>
    content!<br>
</div>
```

**CSS**

There is only one important CSS rule here - It will hide your dropdown area, as opposed to setting it's height, and then having to recall it later with a data attribute.

```
.dropdown{
     display: none;
}
```

**Javascript (commented!)**

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.item').click(function(){
        $('.toggled').slideUp();
        //will take anything with the class "toggled" and slide it up!  Take out this line if you want multiple areas to be able to be expanded at once
        $(this).next('.dropdown').slideToggle().addClass('toggled');
        //this will take the ".item" and find the next div with the class of "dropdown" and slideToggle it.  It also adds the class "toggled" to be used with the previous line.
    });
});
```

This should be fairly straightforward to merge with your site.  Just add the Javascript in place of the one you have, add the CSS rule, and take out the `style="98px;"` attribute on the `.dropdown` class, as that rule gives it an incorrect height.

Let me know if you need any more help or clarification!